# How import Ant project to Eclipse, if project outside of workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an **STS IDE (Eclipse)** and bunch of legacy **ant** projects. Due of fact these are legacy they use libraries from local, and I cannot store them in Eclipse workspace, as folders structure described in **build.xml** and properties files, so folders structure is:

```
/opt/projects
         /Libraries
         /Projects
            /Project1
            /Project2
```

I able to build projects with command line ant. But I cannot get how to import them to Eclipse. What I did:

**1. New - project - Java project from existing Ant Buildfile**

This shows me project imported, but none of java or other source files available, but only build.xml. Also Eclipse able to find some of Libraries. If I run as ant build I get an error

BUILD FAILED
/home/pm/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/Project1/build.xml:179: /home/pm/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/Project1/${libraries.home}/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/dist does not exist.

Then I tried second option:

**2. New - project - Java project** - and set location of my Project1 folder

In this case I see source files and able to run ant build.xml. But Eclipse have no idea about /opt/projects/Libraries as it not taken build.xml into consideration when create project, so it flags: cannot resolve dependencies.

build.xml have quite a lot of dependencies, so I would like to not add them manually to project to not mess with versions in case of build.xml update.

How to import ant projects to Eclipse so the files are available to edit and dependencies are taken using build.xml file? Also it could be nice to be able to build from Eclipse

Comment: An Ant `build.xml` file does not have to be in the workspace or in a project to run it. Just create a new Ant tool configuration, set the _Buildfile_, the _Base Directory_ and properties etc. like you do on the command line

Comment: Not sure I understand you right here: "Just create a new Ant tool configuration...". Should I do this in Eclipse? To clarify I have a build.properties file and it in same folder where build.xml

Comment: Yes, in Eclipse. Probably the problem is caused by relative paths used in the Ant script. So make sure, in Eclipse, in the Ant launch configuration the _Base Directory_ is set to the same directory where you call the Ant command on the command line.

Comment: Yes, this helps - I can build from Eclipse now. Also eclipse shown me sources of java files, but only few of dependencies imported (most of them not imported). Why it not resolves all dependencies from build.xml?